# For a Closed-source Python Library, do you need a setup.py file or is that just for PyPi publication? This package will only be used amongst my team

Tags: python, package, pypi

I am creating an internally used Python library for my company. I have included a README on the src level. Then have project and tests folders additionally stemming from the src. When we are not planning on publishing publicly, do we need a setup.py file (and additionally a LICENSE file)? Thanks!

Right now my file structure is:

```
Project/
|-- project/ 
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- main.py
|-- tests
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- tests.py
|-- README
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a private registry for python packages, and you want other team members be able to install it via that, you need a `setup.py`. Or if you want others be able to install it locally by having `.whl`, you need a `setup.py` to build a package and pass it to your teammate.

You can learn about it [here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) and [here](https://realpython.com/pypi-publish-python-package/#prepare-your-package-for-publication).

And it's a good idea to have a `LICENSE` file, also for a private package. You can set a proprietary license, to restricts the use, modification, and distribution of the software to only the original licensee.

Comment: If I wanted to have them install it locally, what would the setup file look like? Thank you!

Comment: I added some tutorials in the answer for you.@antv2291

Comment: Based on these tutorials I also need to add a .toml file?

Comment: It's good practice to have that, although you can just have `setup.cfg` and a `setup.py` with simply invoking `setup()` from `setuptools`. @antv2291

Comment: In terms of the setup.py I can simply have:

from setuptools import setup

setup()

?

Comment: Yes! With a well written `setup.cfg`. @antv2291